# Visible not showing in Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have the following ko.computed:

```
self.itemsInBasket = ko.computed(function(){
            return self.selectedDomains.length > 0;
        });
```

This is to be shown if this is clicked and incrementing value:

```
this.addToCart = function(viewModel, event) {     
            console.log('click');
            self.selectedDomains(self.selectedDomains() +1);
        }
```

In my html I am using the following data-bind:

```
<div class="domains__selected" data-bind="visible:  $root.domainSearch.selectedDomains.itemsInBasket">
<strong><span class="update--domain" data-bind="text: domainSearch.selectedDomains">&nbsp;</span>&nbsp; Domains selected</strong>
</div>
```

And it is incrementing fine, but it doesnt show the counter.

Can anyone spot whats wrong or point me in the correct direction I would be thankful :)

Comment: You're checking the `length` property of the `selectedDomain` observable that you increment which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: if it's not obvious from JohnnyHK's comment, you need to evaluate the observable before you check the length, otherwise you're checking the length of a function. do this in your itemsInBasket function: `return self.selectedDomains().length > 0;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution worked for me:

```js
self.selectedDomains = ko.observable("");
    self.itemsInBasket = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.selectedDomains() > 0;
    });

    self.addToCart = function () {
        console.log('click');
        self.selectedDomains(self.selectedDomains() + 1);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class="domains__selected" data-bind="visible:  selectedDomains() ">
    <strong><span class="update--domain" data-bind="text: selectedDomains">&nbsp;</span>&nbsp; Domains selected</strong>
</div>
<a class="btn btn-default btn-warning btn-xs"
   data-bind="click: addToCart.bind($data)">
    Update
</a>
```

Comment: This solution worked as inteded! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
self.itemsInBasket = ko.computed(function(){
        return self.selectedDomains() > 0;
    });
```

Comment: This doesnt really fix it. It doesnt increment it just adds number to the Array, and the visible binding still didnt update :-/

Comment: try this: 

self.itemsInBasket = ko.computed(function(){
            return self.selectedDomains() > 0;
        });

Comment: Nope doesnt update the dom. It keeps having style="display: none;"

Comment: Also change the binding in the html to evaluate the parent observable: data-bind="visible:  $root.domainSearch.selectedDomains().itemsInBasket">  I think ko will know how to evaulate itemsInBasket on its own